# Find the order of $\sqrt[3]{2}(1+\zeta_3)$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}(1-\zeta_3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Find the order of $\sqrt[3]{2}(1+\zeta_3)$ and $\sqrt[3]{2}(1-\zeta_3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

I am not sure how to tackle this problem.

MY notes:

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$ has degree 6. The degree of both elements is $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. I have never done a problem like this so I am not sure how to proceed. The first one I can do as it is a root of $x^3+2$. How do i deal with the second one

Comment: You don't mean "order". You mean *degree*: find the degree of each number over $\mathbf Q$, i.e., the degree of their minimal polynomial over $\mathbf Q$.  What do you find if you let ${\rm Gal}(\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)/\mathbf Q)$ act on one of these numbers? You can show two numbers in a field extension are different if they don't have all equal coefficients for a basis of the field extension.

Comment: @KCd so for example if non of the elements of the galois group fix the second element, then it must be of degree 6?

Comment: If no *non-identity* element fixes $\alpha$ then of course $\alpha$ generates the field extension (the field it generates has trivial fixed group, which corresponds to the top field).

Answer (score 1):

While not as quick as the suggestions in the comment, here is another way to deduce that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}(1 + \zeta_3)) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$: Note that

$$[\sqrt[3]{2}(1 + \zeta_3)]^3 =2(1 + \zeta_3)^3 = 2 + 6\zeta_3 + 6 \zeta_3^2 + 2\zeta_3^3 $$

Since $\zeta_3^3 = 1$, we have that $[\sqrt[3]{2}(1 + \zeta_3)]^3 = 4 + 6\zeta_3 + 6\zeta_3^2$. After subtracting $4$ and dividing by $6$, we see that $\zeta_3 + \zeta_3^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}(1 + \zeta_3))$. Note that,

$$(\zeta_3 + \zeta_3^2)^2 = \zeta_3^2 + 2\zeta_3^3 + \zeta_3^4 = 2\zeta_3^2 + 2 $$

After dividing by $2$ and subtracting $1$, we see that $\zeta_3^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}(1 + \zeta_3))$. After squaring we see that $\zeta_3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}(1 + \zeta_3))$. You can now deduce that $\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}(1 + \zeta_3))$. Hence,

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}(1 + \zeta_3)) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\zeta_3)$$

A similar technique works with $\sqrt[3]{2}(1 - \zeta_3)$